# How to completely disable video acceleration?

Tags: video, arm

The issue is with a custom linux rk3066(ARM) build.
When I try to play a video file, X-server crashes with segmentation fault and I get:

```
main vout display error: failed to resize display.
```

I am sure video acceleration is not supported for this build at least, so I want to disable it completely for now.

How do I do this?
The 'screenshot':
[image: oops]